# Next time we get a new PC, what is a good way to partition the hard drive right away for dual boot or multiboot later?

Tags: windows, partitioning, multi-boot

Say if we get a PC desktop or notebook next time, we can partition right away so that if we need to install Windows 8 Consumer Review 32 bit, 64 bit, and install Windows 8 both 32 bit and 64 when they release, it will be ready.  (or even keep 2 more partitions ready for installing Ubuntu).

What is a good way to go about doing that?

---

Some more details:

Most hard drive come with two primary partitions already, one for C:, and one for Factory / Restore Image, so there can be only two more primary partitions only.  Should we use these two, or create one extended partition and then we can create 5 or 6 logical partitions within the extended partitions and those 5, 6 logical partition can be used to install different versions of Windows 8?  Does an extended partition count as one of the primary partitions? (because we are limited to 4 maximum).

Comment: You seem to be asking 4 or 5 questions. Stick with one, and run with it.

Comment: I asked 1 question 5 hours ago.  It got answered.  And now I asked two questions.  These two questions are unrelated.  That's it

Comment: "How should I partition my drive for multiple Windows 8 installations?" "Does an extended partition count as a primary partition?" "Can Windows 8 boot off a logical partition?" "Can multiple Windows 8 installations boot off separate logical partitions?"

Comment: I see what you mean... these are related concepts... I can put them into separate questions, but they may seem weird as another person may say "why do you care whether extended partition count as primary or not?".  I am sure other people face the same issue: how do they go about partitioning after they got a new computer.

Comment: Windows8 should be able to use (and boot off) GPT partition tables, use them, no problem with that 4max limit.

Comment: @Walter 4max?  The thing is, 2 are already used by Win 7 and the factory recovery data.  So two left.  I want to actually have 2 for Win 8 Consumer Preview, 1 or 2 for Ubuntu, and 1 for Win 8 final release... after that I can remove the Consumer Review version, but at a later time, or install Win 9 at a later time too, so more partition can be more flexible

Comment: Ugh, I'm having multiboot flashbacks to the late 90s. Sure you can't use VMs?

Comment: You answered your own question, Logical partition with extended partitions, see this reference...http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/How-to-repartition-HDD-of-HP-notebook-with-pre-loaded-Windows-7/m-p/742019

Comment: @ckhan  but can VM be so powerful to see the graphics capabilities of a brand new OS?